# Can anyone identify this pusher plane from apparently the 1930s?

Tags: general-aviation, aviation-history, aircraft-identification, single-engine, propeller-aircraft

I have performed two searches - a photo search and also an FAA NC number search and failed at both to identify this pusher airplane.  My family photo says it was taken by my mother at the Chicago airport in September 1937.  The NC number appears to be NC 15574 and I've tried several variations including dropping the "1" and trying "9" for the "4" but could not get an FAA NC match.  Your assistance in identifying this airplane and anything about it is greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: If this is supposed to be a family photo taken by your mom, why does it have a copyright watermark with *your* name on it?

Comment: My mother passed away at 100 years old two years ago.  She was an avid photographer and aviation enthusiast, which she passed on to me, and she also passed on all of her photography to me, over 30,000 photographs and slides.  I inherited the copyright from her as curator and as you noted her, give her credit for her photography.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is a [Stearman-Hammond Y-S1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stearman-Hammond_Y-1), registration NC15524, construction  number 309.

The remains of the aircraft are now owned by the Dutch aviation museum  Aviodrome. They are planning to restore one of the four Stearman-Hammonds they have into flyable condition. This project is running since 2007, and is progressing very slowly.

[image: A picture of a Stearman-Hammond Y-S1]

<sub>source: [Smithsonian National Air and Space Museum](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/stearman-hammond-y-1s/nasm_A19560046000)</sub>

Comment: yep, also the number is 15524. Destroyed on 4th nov 1941

Comment: @Federico, where did you find that the aircraft was destroyed in 1941?

Comment: According to the FAA registration webpage, the S-H Y-1S was deregistered Nov. 4, 1941 and listed as destroyed.      DEREGISTERED AIRCRAFT
Deregistered Aircraft 1 of 1
Aircraft Description
Serial Number 309 Certificate Issue Date 10/25/1941
Manufacturer Name STEARMAN-HAMMOND 
Model Y-1S
Year Manufacturer 1937 Cancel Date 11/04/1941
Reason For Cancellation Destroyed 
Type Registration Partnership  
Aircraft Registration Prior to Deregistration
Name GREEN A B & SABIN GLEN L  
Street MUNICIPAL AIRPORT  
City BILLINGS  
State MONTANA Zip Code 59101
Country UNITED STATES

Comment: @FreshBreeze thank you. The FAA registration webpage was down when I checked earlier.

Comment: Some other pictures: https://www.google.com/search?q=stearman+hammond&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi8ktqHx9PuAhVEk54KHXFAACkQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=stearman+hammond&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECAAQHjIECAAQGDoGCAAQBRAeOgYIABAIEB5QhZoFWP25BWDNwgVoAHAAeACAAb0BiAHzCZIBAzAuN5gBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=tKYdYLzoGcSm-gTxgIHIAg&bih=501&biw=1158&client=firefox-b-1-d